# How do you store a single row fetched from a MySQL database in a variable?

Tags: c#, mysql

After running a MySqlCommand and then reading a row with MySqlDataReader, is it possible to store that entire row into a single variable?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    // Store a single row into a variable
    // Pass the variable into another method
}
```

Comment: `var str = rdr.GetString(0)`

Comment: @Rakitić Wouldn't this just store the value from the first column? I'm asking how to store the entire row

Comment: The best thing you can achieve is explained in the MSDN docs about the [IDataRecord interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx), but at the end you still need to read each single column and store them somewhere.

Comment: A more engineered approach is to have a class that represents the data from your record, create an instance of that class and initialize its properties, then pass the instance to another method

Comment: Agree with Steve, it is not terribly useful, but `GetValues()` will populate an array of object. So your "record" could be an object array.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can achieve is explained in the MSDN docs about the [IDataRecord interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx), but at the end you still need to read each single column and store them somewhere.
   
However a more object oriented approach is to have a class that represents the data from your record, create an instance of that class and initialize its properties, then pass the instance to another method

So suppose that the query you have used is a simple

```
SELECT IDPerson, FirstName, LastName from Persons
```

Now you have defined somewhere your class Person

```
public class Person
{
    public int IDPerson {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Then your loop works with

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    // Declare and initialize the instance of a Person 
    // (this is a single variable as per your requirements)
    Person p = new Person()
    { 
       IDPerson = rdr.GetInt32(0),
       FirstName = rdr.GetString(1),
       LastName  = rdr.GetString(2)
    };
    ProcessPerson(p);
}
```